# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{7}}e^{x}}$?

Tags: integration, gamma-function

I am trying to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^{7}}e^{x}}$.

I worked out the answer to be $\Gamma[-\frac{5}{2}]$, However when I used mathematica to check my answer it says the the integral does not converge for $(0,\infty)$ so does that mean that my answer is wrong?

Comment: I'm afraid Mathematica is right: the integral is improper both at 0 and infinity, and $\int_{0}^1 ... dx$ is not convergent.

Comment: Yes, your answer is wrong. That integral diverges. The most likely error is this: You used some formula for $\Gamma(t)$ but you ignored the conditions under which that formula is valid. For example, $\Gamma(t)=\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx$, _if_ $t>0$ (or if $t$ is a complex number with positie real part). You can't use that formula for $\Gamma(-5/2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica is right. This integral does not converge.

The integral representation for $\Gamma$ function
$$ \Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1} e^{-x}\,dx
$$
is only valid for $\Re z > 0$.

To show that your integral diverges, observe that
$$ \int_\delta^1 x^{-7/2} e^{-x}\,dx \geq \frac{1-\delta}{e} \int_\delta^1 x^{-7/2}\,dx
$$
Letting $\delta \to 0$, you can see that your integral does indeed diverge.